# eclipse for java- how to add support for jsf 2.1 to eclipse 3.7-indigo

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I was working on a JSF 2.1 project in Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)- however I needed to use a plugin which has not been updated to work in Eclipse 4.2- so I installed Eclipse 3.7-Indigo and tried opening the JSF project in Eclipse Indigo.

However this is the error message I am getting --

```
Implementation of version 2.1 of project facet jst.jsf could not be found. Functionality will be limited.
```

How do I fix this problem? The project I am using utilises JSF 2.1 and PrimeFaces.

Comment: Which server you are using with eclipse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should actually have edited the JSF facet version in the *Project Facets* entry in the project's properties to before importing the project in an older Eclipse version which doesn't support the newer JSF facet version.

If you can't do it for some reason, then you can also manually change it by going to the `.settings` folder in the Navigator view, opening the `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` file and editing

```
<installed facet="jst.jsf" version="2.1"/>
```

into

```
<installed facet="jst.jsf" version="2.0"/>
```

Comment: is it possible to fix the issue and keep the version 2.1 ?